# Silent installation SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, silent-installer

I need to install SQL Server Express with a Silent Installation, using a configuration file. I created a configuration file, but when I execute the `setup.exe` and pass the file as parameter, I get the following error:

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>   The specified value for setting 'MEDIALAYOUT' is invalid. The expected values are:
>
> None
>
> Core
>
> Advanced
>
> Full
>
> Error code 0x84B40001.

My command to start the installation is:

```
setup.exe /configurationfile = C:\Users\desenv01\Desktop\SQL Server 2014\Configuration\ConfigurationFile.ini.
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: what is in your configuration file?

Comment: Your file has spaces in it, have you tried enclosing the filename in double-quotes? Like `"C:\Users\desenv01\Desktop\SQL Server 2014\Configuration\ConfigurationFile.ini"`

Comment: I tried it, but isn't working. I get the same error

Comment: Actually, the error is diferent. Thank you, bro. I'll try to solve